# How to move files out of subdirectories with given extension recursively to a destination-folder?

Tags: command-line, find

I want to move all the `*.txt` files from all the subdirectories located in a given directory to one destination-directory.

When doing it as below, it moves EVERY file - how can I reduce it to all the `*.txt` files only?

```
find -type f -print0|xargs -0r mv -it "/path to my folder/destination-directory"
```

Comment: try: `find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0|xargs -0r mv -it "/path to my folder/destination-directory"`

Answer (score 11):

Use a glob pattern with `-name` option of `find` to indicate the desired pattern, `*.txt` in your case:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec mv -t /destination {} +
```

Of course, replace `/destination` with the actual destination directory.

**Notes:**

- You don't need to spawn `xargs` and an anonymous pipe, use the `mv` logic within the `-exec` predicate of `find`
- `find ... -exec` handles all kind of possible filenames and `ARG_MAX` as well
- GNU `mv` (default in Ubuntu) has `-t` to take a destination directory, so that you can leverage the `+` argument of `-exec` to send all files in single run of `mv` (or at least minimal runs if `ARG_MAX` is triggered in the process)

Answer (score 6):

Add a `-name` test

```
find -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 |...
```

Don't forget to quote the glob to prevent shell expansions.

For case-insensitive search, use `-iname` instead of `-name`

Answer (score 3):

```
find /folder/ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec mv {} /other/folder/ \;
```

I tested this, works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Using your original command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0|xargs -0r mv -it /path/to/destination
```

Info:

1. `.`: search in current location
2. `"*.txt"`: files that have a `.txt` extension in their names